# RSpec でNoMethodError: undefined method 'post' for #<RSpec::....でハマっています

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

勉強とポートフォリオ製作として以下のページを参考にRSpecでテストをしていたのですが、
User Specテストで詰まってしまいました。

[Rails チュートリアル（7章）をRSpecでテスト](https://qiita.com/sakakinn/items/41c0f39152c3713fefc4)

解決法をご教授いただければ有難いです。

#### やったこと

当初はsignup_pathがundefinedですと怒られていたのですが、QiitaやStackoverflowの記事から rails_helper.rb内に`config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers`を入れてみたところ、エラーが変化して現状のものになりました。

**環境:**
Ruby 2.7.4
Rails 6.0.3

---

gemfileのテストの部分は以下です

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug',            '11.0.1', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem 'factory_bot_rails'
  gem 'rspec-rails',       '~> 5.0'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
  gem 'sqlite3',           '1.4.2'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara',                 '3.28.0'
  gem 'guard',                    '2.16.2'
  gem 'guard-minitest',           '2.4.6'
  gem 'minitest',                 '5.11.3'
  gem 'minitest-reporters',       '1.3.8'
  gem 'rails-controller-testing', '1.0.4'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver',       '3.142.4'
  gem 'webdrivers',               '4.1.2'
end
```

rails_helper.rbの主だった中身です

```
require 'spec_helper'
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../config/environment', __dir__)
abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?
require 'rspec/rails'


begin
  ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!
rescue ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError => e
  puts e.to_s.strip
  exit 1
end
#capybara内のmethodを読み込む
require 'capybara/rspec'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!

  config.filter_rails_from_backtrace!

  config.include FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods
  
  config.before(:each, type: :system) do
    driven_by :selenium_chrome_headless
  end

  config.include ApplicationHelper

  #signup_pathがundefinedと言われたので入れてみた
  config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  #強制的にCapybara::DSLを読み込む
  config.include Capybara::DSL
end

Shoulda::Matchers.configure do |config|
  config.integrate do |with|
    with.test_framework :rspec
    with.library :rails
  end
end
```

spec/factories/users.rbの中身です

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user do
    name { 'Example User' }
    sequence(:email) { |n| "user_#{n}@example.com" }
    password { 'password' }
    password_confirmation { 'password' }
  end
end
```

問題のspec/models/user_spec.rbの該当箇所です

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe User, type: :model do
  
  # factory botが存在するかのテスト
  it 'has a valid factory bot' do
    expect(build(:user)).to be_valid
  end

(中略)

  describe 'POST #create' do
    #有効なユーザーの検証
    context 'valid request' do
      #ユーザー追加される
      it 'adds a user' do
        expect do
          # 下のpostがundefinedと言われる
          post signup_path, params: { user: attributes_for(:user) }
        end.to change(User, :count).by(1)
      end
      #ユーザーが追加された時の検証
      context 'adds a user' do
　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　# 下のpostがundefinedと言われる
        before { post signup_path, params: { user: attributes_for(:user) } }
        subject { response }
        #showページへリダイレクトされる
        it { is_expected.to redirect_to user_path(User.last) } 
        #リダイレクト成功
        it { is_expected.to have_http_status 302 }
      end
    end
    #無効なリクエスト
    context 'invalid request' do
      #無効なデータの作成
      let(:user_params) do
        attributes_for(:user, name: '',
                              email: 'user@invalid',
                              password: '',
                              password_confirmation: '')
      end
      #ユーザーが追加されないことの検証
      it 'does not add a user' do
        expect do
　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　# 下のpostがundefinedと言われる
          post signup_path, params: { user: user_params }
        end.to change(User, :count).by(0)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

ターミナルで表示されるエラー内容は以下です。

```
User
  has a valid factory bot
  validations
    is expected to validate that :name cannot be empty/falsy
    is expected to validate that :email cannot be empty/falsy
    is expected to validate that the length of :name is at most 50
    is expected to validate that the length of :email is at most 255
    is expected to allow :email to be ‹"first.last@foo.jp"›、‹"user@example.com"›、‹"USER@foo.COM"›、‹"A_US-ER@foo.bar.org"›, or ‹"alice+bob@baz.cn"›
    is expected not to allow :email to be ‹"user@example,com"›、‹"user_at_foo.org"›、‹"user.name@example."›、‹"foo@bar_baz.com"›, or ‹"foo@bar+baz.com"›
    validate uniqueness of email
      is invalid with a duplicate email
  before_save
    #email_downcase
      makes email to low case
  validatetions
    is expected to validate that the length of :password is at least 6
    validate presence of password
      is invalid with a blank password
  POST #create
    valid request
      adds a user (FAILED - 1)
      adds a user
        example at ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:73 (FAILED - 2)
        example at ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:75 (FAILED - 3)
    invalid request
      does not add a user (FAILED - 4)

Failures:

  1) User POST #create valid request adds a user
     Failure/Error: post signup_path, params: { user: attributes_for(:user) }
     
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `post' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::User::POSTCreate::ValidRequest:0x00007fa90a96e0f0>
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:65:in `block (5 levels) in <main>'
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:64:in `block (4 levels) in <main>'

  2) User POST #create valid request adds a user 
     Failure/Error: before { post signup_path, params: { user: attributes_for(:user) } }
     
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `post' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::User::POSTCreate::ValidRequest::AddsAUser:0x00007fa90a98e828>
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:70:in `block (5 levels) in <main>'

  3) User POST #create valid request adds a user 
     Failure/Error: before { post signup_path, params: { user: attributes_for(:user) } }
     
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `post' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::User::POSTCreate::ValidRequest::AddsAUser:0x00007fa8fe3e9988>
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:70:in `block (5 levels) in <main>'

  4) User POST #create invalid request does not add a user
     Failure/Error: post signup_path, params: { user: user_params }
     
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `post' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::User::POSTCreate::InvalidRequest:0x00007fa8fe3f00d0>
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:90:in `block (5 levels) in <main>'
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:89:in `block (4 levels) in <main>'

Finished in 0.39295 seconds (files took 2.59 seconds to load)
15 examples, 4 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:63 # User POST #create valid request adds a user
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:73 # User POST #create valid request adds a user 
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:75 # User POST #create valid request adds a user 
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:88 # User POST #create invalid request does not add a user
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

このテストはモデルの単体テスト ([model spec](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/model-specs)) を行うことが期待されています。一方で RSpec の用意する `post` などの DSL は request spec で使われることが想定されています。

```
RSpec.describe User, type: :model do
                           ^^^^^^  ここです
```

このため、どんなテストがしたかったのかによって対処法が変わります。

モデルの単体テストがしたかったのであれば、`post` を使うのはおかしいです。モデルのメソッドをそのまま呼び出し、その挙動を検査してください。

ルーティングまでを含めた結合テスト、つまり request spec がしたかったのであれば、ドキュメント https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/request-specs/request-spec にあるようにテストの定義の仕方を見直してください。

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます。原因は本来requestsのファイル(spec/requests/accesss_to_users_spec.rb)で書くテストをmodelのファイル(spec_models/users.rb)で書いてしまっていました。修正後テスト通ること確認できました。